# sql select values from another table if exist

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help, need to select from table 1, but if entry with the same id exists in table2 should return name and last name from there otherwise values from table1

```
table1

id|name|lastname

1 |    |
2 |    |
3 |    |

table2

id|name|lastname
3 |    |
```

Tried this, but not working

```
SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME
    FROM table1 
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.ID = table1.ID)
```

Comment: It looks like name and lastname are null in both tables so I'm not sure what the lookup will achieve. What is "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if entry with the same `id` exists in `table2` should return `name` and `last name` from there otherwise values from `table1`

You want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then to use `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       COALESCE( t2.name, t1.name ) AS name,
       COALESCE( t2.lastname, t1.lastname ) AS last_name
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ( t1.id = t2.id )
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id, name, lastname ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice1', 'Abbot1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty1', 'Baron1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol1', 'Casey1' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( id, name, lastname ) AS
SELECT 3, 'Carol2', 'Casey2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | LAST_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | Carol2 | Casey2 |
> | 2 | Betty1 | Baron1 |
> | 1 | Alice1 | Abbot1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f58365f4d5f59f50a3e2571b8af9e3e)*

Comment: Thats exactly what i need mate, thank you!